# Magical Records: Loading a record to be updated in a local context

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I am currently saving a record using Magical Records as follows:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objID = [existingItem objectID];
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    CustomNSMO *item;
    if(newItem) item = [CustomNSMO MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
    else item = [localContext objectWithID:objID]; 
    item.sync = 1;
    item.relID = @"Some String";
 }completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
   //do something
 }];
```

This works fine. If I query all items where *sync* has been set I get back the results I expect i.e.

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(sync >= 1)"];
  NSArray *objects = [CustomNSMO MR_findAllSortedBy:@"sync" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate];
```

gives me an array of my new or updated objects.

I then (after some server business) want to find all results with *sync* >= 1 and set it to zero. This is when the strange behaviour occurs. I have been trying to get an array of results within a local context via either

```
  NSManagedObjectContext *localContext    = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
  NSArray *objects = [CustomNSMO MR_findAllSortedBy:@"sync" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];
  for(CustomNSMO *item in objects) {
     item.sync = 0;
  }
  [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

or

```
  [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    NSArray *objects = [CustomNSMO MR_findAllSortedBy:@"sync" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];
    for (SyncObject *currentObj in objects)
    {
        currentObj.sync = @0;
    }
  } completion:nil];
```

If *relID* is set when the item is first created then this is all fine. I can edit the item (changing the *relID*) and the changes is observed in all contexts. However, if the first time the item is created it has a *relID* of *nil* then problems occur after using the code above to do the following:

1) Update the item changing a *nil* *relID* to some non-*nil* value

2) Save the item to the database

3) Load the item (by searching on '*sync*')

In any context apart from *MR_defaultContext* *relID* stays as *nil*. If I look at the object in *MR_defaultContext* then I see the correct updated *relID*. If I look at it in a different context it is *nil*. This means that the update of *sync* on a local context overrides the value of *relID* on the default context (setting it to *nil*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug with the database store we are using below Core Data.

https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/issues/118

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

`if(newItem) item = [CustomNSMO MR_createEntityInContext:context];`

should be:

`if(newItem) item = [CustomNSMO MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];`

You don't want to use a different context inside `+saveWithBlock:`.

Also, this line:

`else item = [localContext objectID];`

I think you mean `[localContext objectWithID:objID]` or `[localContext existingObjectWithID:objID error:error]`?

Comment: You are correct but these were just typos in my example (I simplified down my original code). I've edited the code above.

Comment: Ok, then next make sure you are either refreshing/re-fetching in the contexts that you are not seeing updated values, or else observe the contextDidSave notification and merge changes.

Comment: The context that I'm not seeing the changes in is created just before I change the *sync* property and resave. I would have thought that this context would be based on the values of MR_defaultContext (which does show the changes) and so wouldn't need any merging. The basic process is saveWithBlock, then after that has completed saveWithBlock again. The context of the second block doesn't reflect the changes in the first. But querying defaultContext in the second block does show the changes of the first block.

Comment: Nick, can you try updating MagicalRecord to version 2.3?

Comment: I think I am running 2.3. [MagicalRecord version] returns 230. I'll remove the misleading tag.

Comment: @NickJones could it be a concurrency issue then? Is there any way that the first `+saveWithBlock:` has not completed before the second one is called?

Comment: I did consider that, but I've tried using both the completion block and also sticking in a 10 second delay between saves.

Comment: Is there a simple way to make sure my new context takes on all the changes in the defaultContext? I'd prefer to work out why they are different, but as a short term fix merging the default might work.

Comment: Instead of using `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]`, alloc and init a context with the appropriate concurrency type, and set it's parentContext property to be `MR_defaultContext`